# Redux-Form: How to mock getFormValues in Saga for testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, redux-form, redux-saga

I have created a saga middleware and one of the function need to get the value from redux-form which is using getFormValues. the function is like:

```
export function* loadLogin(action) {
  var login = yield select(getFormValues('login'));
  const { response, error } = yield doAsync(login, loginRequest) || { }
  if (response) {
      yield put(onLoginSuccess(response))
    } else {
      yield put(onLoginFailure(error ? error : "TIMEOUT")); 
    }
}

function* doAsync(func, ...args) {
    const { funcResponse, timeout } = race({
      funcResponse: call(func, ...args),
      timeout: call(delay, TIMEOUT)
    });

    return funcResponse || { }
}
```

It works fine on building develop environment. But it returns undefined in testing. I am using Jest and the test code like this:

```
 describe('When execute process', () => {
      it('Should export ON_LOGIN_SUCCESS response', ()=>{
         const spy = jest.fn();
         const store = createStore(() => ({}));
           const tempform = reduxForm({form: "login"})(Login)
           const props = {
             state:{
              form: {
               login: {
               values: {
                 username: "foo",
                 password: "bar"
                       }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                };
            const mockedComponent = (
              <Provider store={store}>
                 <tempform {...props}>
                  <span />
                </tempform>
              </Provider>
           );
         const tree = renderer.create(mockedComponent).toJSON();
         const gen = loadLogin(tree);
         expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(result);                    
         expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(put(onLoginSuccess(response));
    });
 });
```

I have referred [Redux-Form : How to mock formValueSelector in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433323/redux-form-how-to-mock-formvalueselector-in-jest) to try to mock the value to global state to pass to saga but still not work. How do I mock into it? Is the test code has somethings wrong?